# How to fetch only specified fields of model with DataMapper?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I cant find the way to fetch only necessary fields of model in certain context. Let`s say i have a huge model which has about 30 fields (properties). But for a search purpose i need only couple of them.

Example:

```
class Foo
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String, :length => 256
  property :description, Text
  property :url, String, :length => 4096
  property :city, String, :length => 64
  property :country, String, :length => 64
  property :state, String, :length => 64
  property :created_at, Time
  property :updated_at, Time
  property :expires_at, Time
  ... etc fields ...
end
```

So, for the front-end (web application) most of that fields are used. But for search i need let`s say only :title, :city, :state. Its easy to query data, like that

```
items = Foo.all(:title.like => 'Some stuff')
```

And then i need to pack fetched data into JSON. As far as i know, there is a module for DataMapper called dm-serialize which handles all that operations.

Finally, i do the package for output:

```
response = {:error => 0, :count => items.length, :data => items}
response.to_json
```

But the output items have all the fields while i need to get only some of them. For some reason lazy loading does not work.

The question is: How to specify model fields you are going to select?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Foo.all(:fields=>[:title, :city, :state])
```

Answer (score 4):

Been stumbling over this, too.
Also, provide the `:only` option to `#to_json` method, otherwise it will lazy load the ones not yet fetched.

```
items.to_json(:only => [:title, :city, :state])
```

You have to build the `json` response yourself; otherwise lazy fetches of the other fields will occur.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering how to not force the lazy load when you use to_json